# Visual Studio Community 2015 won't sign in. How do I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio

Whenever I open Visual Studio Community 2015, it asks me to update my license. It won't let me download an updated license, as every time I try, it tells me to check my network or proxy. I do not have a proxy, and my network is just fine.

In addition, when I click the "Add Account" button, which is supposed to let me add an account, it has a message box pop up saying "Configuration system failed to initialize.".

When I click the sign in button, the sign in window pops up, but it disappears immediately, then the program crashes.

Here are a few pictures:
    [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByW3sHReepE5T2ItcDdRcTlfSnM)

How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably a studpid question - can you verify that your ID that you use to sign in is active, correctly spelled etc?

Comment: Yes, I can sign in to microsoft and the visual studio website just fine.

Comment: Kind of hard to trouble-shoot it, since it behaves so erratically and unexpectedly. You probably don't want to hear that and you've probably already considered it yourself but I'll say it anyway. It wouldn't hurt to reinstall the thing or try to install it on a different system. Or with a different LiveID, just to see a pattern of misbehavior that might disclose the actual root cause of the issue.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall it on this pc, and the other one I have is too slow, 2.25gb RAM, and almost crashes opening notepad.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Have you tried the combination reinstalling and trying a rand new Live ID? I'm not recommending a switch of you r identity - just something to try out to exclude some issues and troubleshoot more accurately.

Comment: Live ID? I don't know what that is.

Comment: Live ID is the account you have registered at Microsoft. The one that you try to use when logging in.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.

Comment: With the result that...?

Comment: The same result as I have given.

Comment: It appears as something with your specific machine. I just followed the very same steps and had no problems whatsoever. Are you in position to obtain a new computer?

Comment: No. I am not able to.

Comment: I'm afraid it's something with your specific machine. Given that you've cleaned out the computer and made a full reinstall of the OS and try with a new account, there's no rational reason why it's not working **in a general case**. I've tried those steps and it worked out. I draw a blank here, sorry. You might want to retry the clean-reinstall-rereiger steps again, in case something went missing the last time. Other than that, I'm sorry to tell you but I've got nada. This shouldn't happen. Definitely not to good people like us.   :)

Comment: I agree. If it still does not work, I will need to buy a new pc.

Comment: I've posted a reply to your question. There's nothing new in there, sadly. I just collected and reiterated what's been said in the comments. I don't like questions with no replies on SO.   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's something with your specific machine. Given that you've **cleaned out** the computer and made a **full reinstall** of the OS and tried with a **new account** at Microsoft, there's no rational reason why it's not working in a general case.

I've tried those steps and it worked out. You might want to retry the **clean-reinstall-reregister** steps again, in case something went missing the last time.

As a personal side note I can safely point out that this shouldn't happen. Definitely not to good people like us. :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this when I have a chance.