# VS2015 Community Subscription license is stale

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a Windows Form app that I developed with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.  I recently got a message that my license "has gone stale" and must be updated.  When I click the link, I get an error message: "We could not download a license. Please check your network settings or proxy settings."

Going to my subscription online, I see "Visual Studio Dev Essentials"

I tried the solutions from https://cloudopszone.com/visual-studio-2015-error-message-we-could-not-download-a-license/ without success.  My account is a "work" account and we do not use MFA at this time.

[Visual Studio Community 2015 won't sign in. How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659085/visual-studio-community-2015-wont-sign-in-how-do-i-fix-this) suggests that uninstall/reinstall is needed, so perhaps that is my best next step.
I found the VS2015 installer here: [https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202015&wt.mc_id=o%7Emsft%7Evscom%7Eolder-downloads)

Anyone know if it is possible to update a stale VS2015 license currently?  It occurs to me that MS may have made that impossible somehow since it is an old version.

I installed VS2019 CE to use that, and it opens just fine but my app has issues with fonts (which is a separate issue), and forms look almost ok on screen but very bad when run.

Comment: I uninstalled VS2019 and VS2015, and then downloaded the ISO of VS2015 and reinstalled.   This fails with the exact same error.    The fact that VS2019 prev thought my license was up to date leads me to believe this is related to VS2015 being unsupported.    Guess I need to attack the VS2019 font scale issues in my forms (sigh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused because years ago, I used a "personal" microsoft account, which has the same user id as my "domain" account.  The domain account is what I use for Office 365, Azure, and domain logins.  Apparently VS 2015 was connected to the personal account.  I knew of this personal account, but since I don't use it anymore, I incorrectly assumed it was kaput.

To fix, I opened VS2015, and when prompted to update license, I selected "Add an account..." and entered my userid and noted it was a personal account, and entered that password (different from domain p/w, and thankfully saved in chrome for better or worse).  Then, when I clicked on "Check for an updated license", it found one right away and is now working.